# Elavon Converge - emvchipsale field ssl_tlv_enc

Tags: payment-gateway, emv

I'm working on finishing an integration with a custom POS using an ipp320 and the Elavon Converge platform. I have EMV working with the ipp320 (using RBA SDK) to the authorization request message. Converge message `emvchipsale` for an EMV transaction requires `ssl_tlv_enc` which says it is the "encrypted tlv defining the EMV record" (including transaction amount). I have not been able to figure out where, how or even what data is in the single encrypted hex string.

The person I spoke to at the Elavon integration support did not have any information beyond what the API documentation has.

Does anyone know how to get the information as required by converge?

Answer (score 0):

Answering in hopes someone else will find this useful and saves them a lot of time.

Turns out the documentation was wrong. It should have said "**encoded** tlv defining the EMV record" instead of "**encrypted** tlv defining the EMV record". This is what was causing the confusion. The encoding is documented in the EMV spec sheet.

Some very helpful TLV utilities can be found here: https://emvlab.org/